# Joomla site outputs strange characters instead of website

Tags: php, joomla

I don't realy know how to explain this one correctly, so I'd better depict the whole scenario.

I've got a Joomla site with a custom component and a few custom modules. Everything works fine, but now I have the need to replicate the project and make some implementations, so I created an exact copy of the original project, with its own folder on localhost and his own Mysql DB. This copy ***sometimes***, instead of outputing the website, outputs a series of strange characters (see enclosed image). Sometimes refreshing the page loads the correct content, sometimes it doesn't and I have to revert back to an earlier version of the site. This happens both on front- and backend [image: Weird Joomla Output]

It's realy driving me nuts. I've already tried the obvious things like clearing the cache and looking for corrupted files, but to no avail.

The project is running on localhost (MAMP Free edition), Joomla is 2.5.3 with Gantry Framework installed and it's running a custom component (which is working fine on the original copy of the site)

Has anybody else ever had this kind of behaviour from Joomla? If so, did you resolve?

Comment: How did you make the copies of site and of database? Does the database look okay when you view it in phpmyadmin (or similar application)?  When you say "the website" do you mean every single page view?

Comment: Did you convert utf-8 files to ascii? After you update Joomla with the update package, does the error go away? Was your site hacked?

Comment: I copied the folder of the website and copied the database through phpmyadmin. The DB looks ok when viewed with phpmyadmin. The thing is it sometimes works, then I make a change to a php file or style sheet and it all goes haywire (the whole site, sometimes even the backend) and I have to revert the changes. I haven't tried upgrading, but I exclude hacking (the website I copied was on localhost) Did not convert any file from UTF-8 to ASCII, although not deliberately.